# Simple algorithm to estimate probability based on past occurences?

Tags: algorithm, probability, estimation, consistency

Suppose after N occurrences, there are P times that an event happens. The "naive" approach to estimate the probability of that event happen again the next time is P/N, but obviously the higher N is, the better our estimation.

What is a practical approach to model that "sureness" in the real world? I don't need something mathematically perfect, just something to make it a little bit more realistic. For example:

- if a footballer scores 9 goals in 40 matches then I want the algorithm to rate him higher than a footballer who scores 1 goal in 4 matches
- a movie with a rating of 8.0 with 100k votes should be placed higher than a 8.2 movie with 2k votes
- etc...

Comment: Based on the examples it seems to me that there would be **a formula which would provide a sorting key** but I don't know any more.

Comment: your goal is not very well defined. You should give a better description on what is considered better

Comment: I think that Bayes' theorem is what you're looking for.  It is a simple formula, but its application can be very complex. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem)

Comment: Well the thing is "better" is indeed something very subjective, so I don't need an algorithm that gives a result that everyone will agree upon. Just something "close" is good enough. Another example is in a chess game where the computer learns the behavior of the user, if it sees him making this move 80 times out of 100 then it should expect him doing it more than if the user does it 2 times out of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the wilson-score interval: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval. The wilson-score solves the problem how to sort a 2d array.

Comment: The Bayes' theorem that Ari posted above is easier to implement (just found out this is the algorithm used by imdb for their rating system), but Wilson score interval seems to be a more "accurate" estimation, so I accept this one.